# Merging some values in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm wondering if it is possible to merge certain values in an object to an array/object. I'm currently developing a module to create a quotation and everytime a value is changed in the form I want to send the form data to the server (async ajax call) to auto save the quotation. I'm getting the form data (by `react hook form`'s `getValues()` function) as shown on the screenshot below:

[image: Form data returned by <code>getValues()</code>]

As seen on the screenshot there are multiple lines[0] and lines[1 ] entries that are all seperate entries. To send it to the server I need the data as following:

```
client_id: "686",
condition: "7",
...
lines: {
    0: {
        amount: 1,
        description: 'Test line 1',
        price: 100,
    },
    1: {
        amount: 1,
        description: 'Test line 2',
        price: 200,
    }
},
...
```

Anyone here who knows how I can accomplish to convert my data into something like the example above? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for any key with dots.
Expanded the solution for the square brackets:

```
var source = {
    id:12,
    cond:"true",
    'lines[0].amount':"1",
    'lines[0].description':"a1",
    'lines[1].amount':"1",
    'lines[1].description':"a1",
};

var target = {};
for (var key in source) {
    if (source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        set(target, key, source[key])
    }
}

function set(obj, path, value) {

    obj = typeof obj === 'object' ? obj : {};    
    path = path.replace("[",".").replace("]","")
    var keys = Array.isArray(path) ? path : path.split('.');   
    var curStep = obj;

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {

        var key = keys[i];        
        if (!curStep[key] && !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(curStep, key)){            
            var nextKey = keys[i+1];
            var useArray = /^\+?(0|[1-9]\d*)$/.test(nextKey);
            curStep[key] = useArray ? [] : {};
        }        
        curStep = curStep[key];
    }
    var finalStep = keys[keys.length - 1];
    curStep[finalStep] = value;
};
```

Comment: Hey @MichaelGoldenberg, tried your solution (only re-wrote it in ES6) and did exactly as I was hoping for. Will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general for merging values, folks should check out [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

In this particular case, to go from the second screenshot to the first, you might have used a loop, something like:

```
let newObject = {};
for (let lineIndex=0; lineIndex<lines.length; lineIndex++) {
    for (let fieldIndex=0; fieldIndex<Object.keys(lines[lineIndex]).length; fieldIndex++) {
        let newKey = "lines["+lineIndex+"]."+fieldIndex<Object.keys(lines[lineIndex])[fieldIndex];
        newObject[newKey] = lines[lineIndex][Object.keys(lines[lineIndex])[fieldIndex]]
    }
}
```

To go the other way, you would basically do the inverse.  The details of the best way to do this would depend on how predictable your set of fields are and if you know the length.  Otherwise you could make guesses by iterating over the keys in the flatter object and doing tests like `if(Object.keys(flatterObject)[index].startsWith("lines["))`.

Comment: Hi @WBT, thanks for the answer. It's the other way around actually, the image is what I'm getting and the code "example" is how I want it to be. I was hoping there would exist a 'default' js function for that but apparently not. Will definitely check out the way you are suggesting. The set of data for one field is always the same so I got that already going for me, which is nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do what you want, but before any of that I'd suggest a deeper dive on the library you're using. Here's how to handle arrays in React Hook Form: https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#FieldArrays

After "fixing" that, if you still want `lines: {}` to be an object, not an array, then a simple array `reduce` can build that up for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm already using FieldArrays from React Hook Form though. This is how getValues() returns everything for me.